# Double name="_token" in Request Payload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, csrf

I'm sending an AJAX Post request for uploading files and I'm also sending csrf token via hidden input field in **Laravel app.**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_token_string">
```

but when the request finishes it ends with a token mismatch error.

When I look into the Request payload it looks like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryITlzaMkvRml5kPVz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

j6LzcmRPzZy9LV7cZonYvIuQXBELLtUhUw2Jh5jv
------WebKitFormBoundaryITlzaMkvRml5kPVz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

j6LzcmRPzZy9LV7cZonYvIuQXBELLtUhUw2Jh5jv
------WebKitFormBoundaryITlzaMkvRml5kPVz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screen Shot 2016-01-14 at 18.27.40.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryITlzaMkvRml5kPVz--
```

As you can seem `form-data; name="_token"` appears twice.

Is it possible that the **WebKitFormBoundary** is "overwriting" my csrf token which has the same name, and therefore the application is reporting a token mismatch?

Comment: Nah, the boundaries do not “overwrite” anything. They are automatically generated out of the “input data”, i.e. the elements in your form – so if you see the same name=value pair within different boundaries, that rather suggests that your form does contain _two_ such elements. Are you sure that you form does not contain the token already, before you add your hidden input field …?

Comment: yes there is only one input field with name="_token" in my form

Comment: Well then we need to see more code … What does your AJAX function that sends the request look like?